# Meteor site locks up when trying to add new account

Tags: meteor, mup

I recently updated my Meteor based website from 1.3 to 1.8, while including a Let's Encrypt SSL.  When I attempt to add new users after being deployed using MUP, the UI for adding users collapses down to three strobing bars but never completes.  When I attempt to run the page in another browser it gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error.  This 502 error goes away when I refresh the original page attempting to create the account.

I built around using the 'turn key' accounts as provided.  It works great while testing locally on my home computer.

This is all the install packages including the default after removing insecure and :

```
meteor-base@1.4.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.6.2                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.2.0                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.5.3   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.4.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
ecmascript@0.12.4              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.4.0            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

alexwine:bootstrap-4
oauth
iron:router
accounts-ui
accounts-password
accounts-facebook
accounts-google
session
underscore
facebook-config-ui
google-config-ui
```

And this is running stock accounts, there is no special code.  I have set up the sign in for username and email in the client facing side of the JavaScript file:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_AND_EMAIL"
});
```

What is really frustrating is that my site works fine when ran on my local machine for testing, adding and updating users as necessary, but gets bogged down when deployed for some reason.

I'm so lost I don't even know know what would be causing it to hang like this so badly.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Adding package.json

```
{
  "name": "DMachineWordBank",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error on the server when creating a new user? Also can you update your post to include package.json.

Comment: I added the package.json file.  I'm having a hell of a time finding where the errors are stored server side after using mup.   The only error message I can get from Docker says "node: symbol lookup error: /bullt_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lE" before restarting.

Comment: You can run `mup logs -f --tail=100` from your mup directory to see the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you remove bcrpt and ignore the following message does it fix production?

```
Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
(STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
In order to use the native implementation instead, run

    meteor npm install --save bcrypt

in the root directory of your application.
```

Comment: I did that before, now running with bcrypt@3.0.6, but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Ok, this sent me down the right path, thanks!  My solution was basically to roll back to v0.8.6.  Now I can create accounts at least.